# css 100% width don't work when zooming

Tags: css

I have here some code

```css
.container{
 height: 200px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: black;
}

.container_1{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    height: 200px;
 width: 20000px;
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_1">

</div>

<div class="container">
  
</div>
```

If you scroll to right side, the `.container` stopped. But I gave him a with of 100%, why it won't work?

Answer (score 2):

It is 100% of its parent, which is the body. The body didn't get an explicit width, so it's just as wide as the client size of the window. The other div is forced to be wider (20000px), so it extends outside of the bounds of the body.

In the snippet below, I've added a border to the body, so you can see how the second div snugly fits into that boundary.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.container_1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 20000px;
  background-color: black;
}
body {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_1">

</div>

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because its 100% of the view port

Try this,

```
.main_container{
    float:left;
}

.container{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

.container_1{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 20000px;
    background-color: black;
}



<div class="main_container">

<div class="container_1">

</div>

<div class="container">

</div>

</div>
```